# Django - creating XML file from Template - MemoryError

Tags: python, django, io, django-templates

I'm getting `MemoryError` when trying to create an `XML` file using `Django` templates.

```
class Export(TimeStampedModel):
    xml_file = models.FileField(upload_to='exports/', null=True, blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def generate_and_save(cls):
        export = Export.objects.create()
        string = render_to_string('exporter/export.xml', {'object_list': Product.objects.active()})
        now_string = now().strftime('%d%m%Y_%H%M%S')
        export.xml_file.save(f"export_{now_string}.xml", ContentFile(string))
```

The problem is obvious. There are hundreds of thousands of products and the whole rendered template is stored in memory until written to file.

Is it possible to do it in chunks or stream?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/peopledoc/django-chunkator